# Swift WebView и белый экран в симуляторе. Что не так? В симуляторе белый экран. Загрузка сайта не происходит

Tags: ios, swift, webview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView! 

func loadAddressUrl(){

    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/"){
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        webview?.scalesPageToFit = true
        webview?.loadRequest(request)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadAddressUrl()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: А в консоль что-нибудь полезное выводит программа?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http. Может это поможет.

Comment: В консоле тишина, ошибок нет.. webview.loadRequest(request)  если убрать ? ,то ругается на отсутствие webview

Comment: Глупый вопрос, а Вы в сториборде все верно подключили? Как вариант имплементируйте UIWebViewDelegate и посмотрите, что вернет func webView(UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError: Error)

Comment: А где инициализируется _webview_? собственно оператор `?.` и пропускает операции когда объект _null_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте ключ доступа в Info.plist:

[image: Настройки проекта]

Словарь "App Transport Security Settings", ключ "Allow Arbitrary Loads", значение "YES"

Comment: не помогло решить проблему

Comment: Вот работающий образец, попробуйте: https://github.com/nightsilf/TestWebViewSwift

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на логи приложения. 
- Если доступ к сайту рубит ATS, то это выводится в логах. И можно выдать разрешение на доступ к http сайтам
- Если логи чистые, вполне возможно что в storyboard аутлет подключен не верно или не подключен вовсе
- Ещё можно попробовать убрать weak
- И добавить к webView свой делегат (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate). UIWebViewDelegate содержит список методов, которые вызываются по мере загрузки очередного ресурса. Соответственно, добавив логгирование вы увидете ход загрузки

Comment: Логи пустые, ошибок нет..  App Transport Security Settings проблемы не решил..((